# Putty's freezes at home but works fine at office

Tags: windows, ubuntu, freeze, putty

I've an interesting problem.

Connecting to Ubuntu Server 16.04 from my Windows 7 through Putty freezes on my home network. "ls -l" displays a few lines and freezes. Opening vi makes the screen blank. It never comes back after that.

strace with any Linux shell command freezes as well. I tried rebooting Windows and Linux both. Tried different versions of Putty. Nothing helped me.

Same works without any problems from my office network. I tried rebooting Windows and Linux both. Tried different versions of Putty. Nothing helped me.

```
   ubuntu@5x:~$ strace ifconfig
   execve("/sbin/ifconfig", ["ifconfig"], [/* 20 vars */]) = 0
   brk(NULL)                               = 0xd0b000
   access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
   fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=27822, ...}) = 0
   mmap(NULL, 27822, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7feb7de1a000
   close(3)                                = 0
   access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK
```

[Putty freeze screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M9d6.png)

Comment: It sounds like there is a communication problem between the 2 machines, and since the connection is not stable / persistent then SSH just freezes. Another option is that there is another application on your Win7 machine that uses port 22 and thus blocks it for Putty's use.

Comment: It happens just with one particular machine. I do not see this issue with other Ubuntu server machines.

Comment: ok, now it is not just me...my colleague has the same problem.

Comment: Perhaps for some reason Putty does not properly keep the session alive. Try the following in your connection settings:
Connection>Enable TCP Keepalives and Connection>Seconds Between Intervals 
Found it here: https://www.lowendtalk.com/discussion/11423/what-to-do-when-putty-freezes

Comment: And another solution: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20195/24500

Comment: @bizna, unfortunately it did not work. The screen freezes right after I login and issue any command.

Comment: Ok... How about checking that your Linux server and Windows machine / network have the same MTU settings? It is very likely that it is not:
http://www.snailbook.com/faq/mtu-mismatch.auto.html

Comment: I've not verified them yet. But the point is everything works well when I'm at office. Same Windows desktop and Ubuntu server.

Comment: When you connect from the office, the MTU differences might be dealt with by any of the routers / switches in the way. When at home, you connect pretty much directly. Check to see if there are MTU differences.

Comment: Is there a way I can verify that? I have access to only my desktop and the Ubuntu server that I'm connecting to through putty. It is set to 1500. I cannot access the underlay network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same exact problem here: Accessing Ubuntu server from home via OpenVPN led to freezes with `ls -l` in certain directories and many other commands. WinSCP also froze when listing certain directories.

Reducing MTU on the VPN connection worked for me:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "Local Area Connection* 2" mtu=1430 store=persistent
netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "Ethernet 2" mtu=1430 store=persistent
```

Thanks, @bizna!

Comment: I used the same VPN connection both in office and from home as well. These days I do not see the issue and not sure what solved the issue.

Comment: Further info that I've learned since:
- This is a known problem with OpenVPN via UDP
- OpenVPN can do an MTU test to figure out a good value and restrict its control package sizes (`mtu-test`)
- For me, adding `mssfix 1409` to my client.ovpn was a more satisfying solution

Relevant further links:
https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/271-i-can-ping-through-the-tunnel-but-any-real-work-causes-it-to-lock-up-is-this-an-mtu-problem
http://wandin.net/dotclear/index.php?post/2009/01/08/OpenVPN-MTU-Size
https://www.sonassi.com/help/troubleshooting/setting-correct-mtu-for-openvpn